# TypeError: webpack.ProvidePlugin is not a constructor

Tags: jquery, node.js, webpack

I'm trying to use a simple bootstrap, jquery plugin `bootstrap-show-password` but on load the page with  form shows an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.

I don't understand why jquery wouldn't be loaded. I did the usual

`npm install bootstrap jquery popper.js --save`

and in my `app.js` I have

```js
//import jQuery from "jquery";
//window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery;
// this should be loaded with webpack, right?! ^

import "bootstrap";
import "bootstrap-show-password";
```

I'm looking at the webpack [docs](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/) and it says to use the the plugin provider, but when I add that to my `webpack.config.js`

```js
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery',
});
```

`npm run build` gives me `TypeError: webpack.ProvidePlugin is not a constructor` error

Did I miss something that needs to be installed?

Here are my `package.json` dependencies

```json
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.17",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.14",
    "eslint": "^7.20.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "htmlnano": "^0.2.8",
    "imagemin-cli": "^6.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "onchange": "^7.1.0",
    "postcss": "^8.2.6",
    "postcss-cli": "^8.3.1",
    "posthtml": "^0.15.1",
    "posthtml-cli": "^0.9.1",
    "posthtml-modules": "^0.7.3",
    "stylelint": "^13.11.0",
    "webpack": "^5.23.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "bootstrap-show-password": "^1.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1"
  }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, after a few hours I found that the culprit was incorrectly initialized `webpack` var in `webpack.config.js`. For reason that's beyond me I had there

```js
const { webpack } = require("webpack");
```

instead of

```js
const webpack = require("webpack");
```

Comment: I had this same error and this was the required fix.  Feel like I just had a denvercoder9 moment, only with the answer https://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: I had the same thing. There is a very popular tutorial for webpack that has that wrong code near the top. My guess it was a copy and paste. This is a very helpful answer for all those that run into the same issue.

Comment: You had { webpack } because VSCode tried to be helpful and inserted it when it saw you type "new webpack.ProviderPlugin"

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue and I was able to resolve it. This was my webpack config initially:

```js
const { webpack } = require("webpack");

...
plugins: [
    ...
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      Buffer: ["buffer", "Buffer"],
    }),
    ...
  ],
...
```

Here's what I did to resolve it:

```js
// Import ProvidePlugin directly
const { webpack, ProvidePlugin } = require("webpack");

...
plugins: [
    ...
    // call the ProvidePlugin constructor directly
    new ProvidePlugin({
      Buffer: ["buffer", "Buffer"],
    }),
    ...
  ],
...
```

`webpack.ProvidePlugin` will only work if you used the default import of webpack like this,

```js
const webpack = require("webpack");
```